# How to forward requests to another URL?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, forward, rule

Currently, I have the following rule in my `httpd.conf` file to forward all requests from port 80 to port 8080 to be served by GlassFish app server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@myserver.com
    ServerName myserver.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I need to add a rule such that all requests to `http://myserver.com/` will be forwarded to `http://myserver.com/page/index.html` and the URL should still appear to be `http://myserver.com/` on the client's browser. I tried to add the following rules inside the above `VirtualHost`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http://myserver.com/ http://myserver.com/page/index.html
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/ http://myserver.com/page/index.html
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/index.html http://myserver.com/page/index.html
```

However, when I go to `http://myserver.com/`, the browser have this error: `This webpage has a redirect loop`. The 3rd rule can only work if I go to `http://myserver.com/index.html`.

I am a total noob at writing rules for Apache. Hence, I'd be very grateful if you could show me what I've done wrong here :).

**UPDATE:**

The following rule works perfectly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /page/index.html [R]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `$` indicating the end of the URI:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ http://myserver.com/page/index.html

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

Without the `$`, the regex `^/` matches `/page/index.html` which will cause it to redirect again, and it'll match again, and redirect again, etc.